# Comparing output of program with the sqlite database

Tags: c#

I am comparing dataVal output with the sqlite database as shown in the code below.
For Example: Lets assume output of dataVal is Kelly. When I run the program, in the first loop string z stores value "K" and then store "Kelly" only after second loop. Can someone please elaborate what is happening here and how to get the value of z as 'Kelly' after first loop?

```
dataVal = string.Join("", dataResult.ToArray());
Aryabase databaseObject = new Aryabase();

if (dataVal.StartsWith('k'))
{
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(databaseObject.myConnection))
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from k where Data like 'k%'", con); 
        con.Open();
        var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string z = Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]);
            if (dataVal == z)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]));
            }
          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the second loop? z is declared inside while, so it's gone once you leave the loop

Comment: Add variable outside the method then inside your `if (dataVal == z)` you can do `yourVariable = z;` after that use yourVariable

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. The first program checks that dataVal starts with the letter k. If so, it returns all records from the k table that the DATA field starts with the letter k. Finally, it checks which record's data value is equal to dataVal and prints it to the output.